# How does Apple add rating stars to callouts on map views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotationview

Trying to do something that shouldn't be this difficult. Trying to display stars for a rating very similar to a screenshot (below) that Apple provides in the Maps Programming Guide for iOS.

Basically in the subtitle of the Annotation callout, I want to show some stars in a different color than the rest of the text in the subtitle.

I really cannot figure out how to do this without going through the entire nonsense of creating an entirely custom callout. They provide some documentation on doing that, but I am trying to avoid it unless I really have to.

As far as I can tell, with the out of the box MKAnnotation protocol, both title and subtitle properties are just NSString...if I could use an attributed string I could make it work, but it doesn't seem possible. Is Apple "cheating" here by creating a custom callout that looks just like the "normal" one?

Will I really need to go through the process of creating an entire custom callout just to do this? I really want to keep all the existing functionality and layout of the native callout.

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

Nevering having used this library, I defer to the documentation which mentions:

> - To provide custom callout views, override the leftCalloutAccessoryView method and use it to return the views.

Although it's under the Subclassing heading for the class documentation, I don't think that means to subclass the entire MKAnnotationView.

The class has a `leftCalloutAccessoryView` property which is not listed as `readonly` and has a default value of `nil`, so presumably you'll need to at least create a custom view, and then set the `MKAnnotationView.leftCalloutAccessory` to it.

The `MKAnnotation` protocol seems to just provide limited information to be used by the `MKAnnotationView`